# List.Distinct() causes my parameter to act like a value type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple list of integers called Numbers. I send this list to 2 methods: the first uses a random to fill the list with 333 numbers between 1 and 100. At the end of the filling I'm using 'Distinct()' on my list to get only the distinct random numbers, and than prints out the amount of items the list has. My second method receive the list and prints out the number of elements in it also, the 'Count' property.

How is it that I'm working on the same list all the time and get different results?

This is my code:

```
class Program
    {

        static List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();
        static Random Rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FillNumbers(Numbers);
            CountNumbers(Numbers);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CountNumbers(List<int> numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are {0} numbers the list", numbers.Count);
        }

        private static void FillNumbers(List<int> numbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 333; i++)
            {
                int n = Rnd.Next(1, 101);
                numbers.Add(n);             
            }
            numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("After distinct there are {0} numbers in the list",numbers.Count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, why would you add non-distinct numbers to the list then filter them? You could instead use a HashSet and either naively add (any dupes would be ignored) or check if the number already exists if you need to track dupes.

Comment: `List` is a reference type, and it's acting exactly like a reference type here.  It is *not* acting like a value type, because it's *not* a value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList();
```

is creating a new list.
This list will contain only the distinct values, but your original list will not.
Calling by reference will fix it:

```
    private static void FillNumbers(ref List<int> numbers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 333; i++)
        {
            int n = Rnd.Next(1, 101);
            numbers.Add(n);             
        }
        numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("After distinct there are {0} numbers in the list",numbers.Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `FillNumbers` you don't mutate the `Numbers` variable.  You first mutate the list that you are given, then you generate a new list based on the distinct values and then assign it to `numbers`, which is a very different variable than `Numbers`.  It is a parameter to that method and that goes away as soon as `FillNumbers` finishes executing.  While you *could* assign the list that you are creating to `Numbers` instead of `numbers`, the best practices would really be to `return` the list and let the caller do what they want with it, and also to not accept a list as input at all, since your goal is to create an entirely new list anyway.

As for why the `CountNumbers` is observing the non-distinct values in the list, that is because when adding the items you were mutating *the list that `numbers` referenced*, rather than *mutating the reference itself*.

Comment: put simply, the FillNumbers function is not changing the Numbers variable. Make FillNumbers return the new list (the numbers variable)

Answer (score -3):

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var numbers = GetNumbers();
       CountNumbers(numbers);

       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   private static void CountNumbers(List<int> numbers)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("There are {0} numbers the list", numbers.Count);
   }

   private static List<int> GetNumbers()
   {
       var random = new Random();
       var numbers = new List<int>();

       for (int i = 0; i < 333; i++)
       {
           numbers.Add(random.Next(1, 101));             
       }

       numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList();
       Console.WriteLine("After distinct there are {0} numbers in the list",numbers.Count);

       return numbers;
   }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the problems with your code snippet still not compiling, your explanation text is also still very wrong.  Change to a list *are* going to be observed.  What isn't observed is changes to the reference to the list.  Now that you've removed your explanation, your answer is still entirely unhelpful.  It doesn't explain why his code does what it does, what you are changing, why those changes are important, etc.